# WebLogic, how to "import" JMS messages in a FileStore?

Tags: jms, weblogic

I have followed on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13701/store.htm#i1149754 the instructions to export (dump) the entire content (message data) of  a JMS FileStore. However the documentation doesn't suggest that you can do the IMPORT in a different filestore.

[This utility](http://www.tomecode.com/2011/02/01/dumping-the-content-or-data-from-weblogic-persistent-store-filestore/) allows to EXPORT, but not to IMPORT the message.

Comment: There is no import because the persistent store is just a .dat file on the file system or in a database table if you used JDBC persistent stores. So importing it would either be putting it back into a DB table outside of weblogic or simply putting the .dat file back into the correct folder...

You can simply re-send the JMS messages you want as well. See the oracle docs to get a better understanding: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13814/storetune.htm

Comment: our use case is the following: a domain runs on a machine which dies, and all the data we can recover is a filestore.dat file on a NFS share. We want to be able to "replay" those JMS messages in a Disaster Recovery (DR) domain - without having to physically replace the whole DR filestore with the one from the crashed site. So I was hoping to be able to export selected messages from the .DAT and import them in the destination DR domain...